# Jquery mobile autocomplete implementation with local json

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement the jquery mobile autocomplete functionality, because i have a list of around 3000 items.

I have a json that has this structure:

```
[{"v1":" abcd","v2":"http://www.url.nl","v3":0487,"v4":"street12","v5":"H"},
{"v1":" qq","v2":"http://www.url.nl","v3":0297,"v4":"street14","v5":"A"},
{"v1":" zz","v2":"http://www.url.nl","v3":0117,"v4":"street55","v5":"A"}]
```

I am using this example: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html

but i can not get this to work with my json file.

```
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
        $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
            var $ul = $( this ),
                $input = $( data.input ),
                value = $input.val(),
                html = "";
            $ul.html( "" );
            if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
                $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: {
                        q: $input.val()
                    }
                })
                .then( function ( response ) {
                    $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                        html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                    });
                    $ul.html( html );
                    $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                    $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I have the feeling that it has to with the ajax call and my json file, but I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: [D-W](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1401620/d-w) undercover ;)

Comment: What have you tried? u just copy pasted the demo code snippet from jQuery Mobile site.

Comment: your array should look like this `(["v1:abc", "v2:efg", "v3:hij"])`

Comment: I tried changing .ajax with .getjson but that didn't work. I also tried changing jsonp to json. Furthermore i was lost to how to work with the json file i have. the lines in my json file represent sport clubs with a website and twitter, so these belong together. I want to display the v1 part for every club